# How to "Receive a Fax Now" using FAXCOMEXLIB?

Tags: c#, fax

I can receive and send fax using FAXCOMEXLIB in C#.
example:

```
nws.faxSrv = new FaxServerClass();
nws.faxSrv.Connect(serverName);nws.faxSrv.ListenToServerEvents(FAXCOMEXLib.FAX_SERVER_EVENTS_TYPE_ENUM.fsetOUT_QUEUE | FAXCOMEXLib.FAX_SERVER_EVENTS_TYPE_ENUM.fsetIN_QUEUE);
nws.faxSrv.OnOutgoingJobChanged += faxSrv_OnOutgoingJobChanged;
nws.faxSrv.OnOutgoingJobAdded += faxSrv_OnOutgoingJobAdded;
nws.faxSrv.OnOutgoingJobRemoved += faxSrv_OnOutgoingJobRemoved;

nws.faxSrv.OnIncomingJobAdded += faxSrv_OnIncomingJobAdded;
nws.faxSrv.OnIncomingJobChanged += faxSrv_OnIncomingJobChanged;
nws.faxSrv.OnIncomingJobRemoved += faxSrv_OnIncomingJobRemoved;
```

How can I use "Receive a Fax Now"? (windows fax have a "Receive a Fax Now" button).

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms690121%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score -1, accepted):

use this:

```
 public void ReceiveFaxNow()
    {
        try
        {
            var device = nws.faxSrv.GetDevices().GetEnumerator();
            device.MoveNext();
            FaxDevice dev = (FaxDevice)device.Current;

            if (dev != null)
            {
                dev.AnswerCall();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

        }
    }
```

Comment: This looks like disassembled code that doesn't even do what you asked. If you want to just pick the first device and call `AnswerCall()` why don't you do just that? `devices[0].AnswerCall()`. If you want to check that there *are* devices, check`devices.Count`.